# Null safety and Maps

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

How do you handle the following case:

```dart
void main() {
  print(getInt('d'));
}

Map<String, int> myMap = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3};

int getInt(String key) {
  if (!myMap.containsKey(key)) {
    myMap[key] = 0;
  }
  return myMap[key]!; 
}
```

`myMap[key]` is never null, but if I remove the `!` of `return myMap[key]!;` I get the null safety error:

> A value of type 'int?' can't be returned from the function 'getInt' because it has a return type of 'int'.

Is it proper to cast away the nullability with `!`, or is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#the-map-index-operator-is-nullable):

> The index [] operator on the Map class returns null if the key isn’t present. This implies that the return type of that operator must be nullable.

```dart
Map<String, int> map = {'a': 1};
int i = map['a']; // Error
```

**Solutions:**

- Use **`??`** and provide a default value.

  ```dart
  int i = map['a'] ?? 0;
  ```
- Use Bang **`!`** operator.

  ```dart
  int i = map['a']!;
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what cleaner means, and the `!` does exist for a reason.

You could simplify that if statement to a single line:

```
int getInt(String key) {
  myMap[key] ??= 0;
  return myMap[key]!; 
}
```

Comment: fyi, assignments in dart also return the value, and then it's even smart enough here to know it's not null. so you could simplify it even more by saying `return myMap[key] ??= 0;`

Comment: @IvoBeckers Nice! That looks even "cleaner".

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get rid of the bang when you're using a map.

This might be a cleaner way to code the same thing.

```
int getInt(String key) => myMap[key] ?? 0;
```